# JS/TS: object destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, destructuring

i've a variable named `props`.
The type extends from `VariantTheme`, `VariantSize`, `VariantGradient`, & `React.DOMAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>`

Then i want to make one more variable, let say `htmlProps`.
I want to fill the `htmlProps` from `props`.
I don't want it filled with a foreign props other than listed on `React.DOMAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>`.
Then spread the filtered prop into react component.

Here the **not working** code:

```
export interface Props
    extends
        VariantTheme,
        VariantSize,
        VariantGradient,
        React.DOMAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>
{
    tag?     : keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
    classes? : string[]
}
export default function Element(props: Props) {
    const elmStyles     = styles.useStyles();

    // themes:
    const variTheme     = useVariantTheme(props);
    const variSize      = useVariantSize(props);
    const variGradient  = useVariantGradient(props);



    const Tag       = (props.tag ?? 'div');
    const htmlProps = props as React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>; // not working! Still containing strange props from VariantTheme, VariantSize, tag, classes, ...
    return (
        <Tag {...htmlProps}
            className={[
                elmStyles.main,
                
                // themes:
                variTheme.class,
                variSize.class,
                variGradient.class,

                ...(props.classes ?? []),
            ].filter((c) => !!c).join(' ')}
        >
            {(props as React.PropsWithChildren<Props>)?.children}
        </Tag>
    );
};
```

Do you have an idea to fix my code?

Comment: Talking about 'not working code'. What exactly is your problem? Error Messages in the console? Not getting the result you expect? Please, be more precise.

Comment: The type system only exists at compile time. You can't use the type-system to do run-time filtering of properties. My advice would be to extend only from `React.DOMAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>` and then to **compose** a type with individual props for each of the other interfaces. Now you'll have an interface with 5 additional, known propnames that you can filter out at run time.

Comment: Here the error: Warning: React does not recognize the `enableGradient` prop on a DOM element. because the htmlProps still contains strange props from VariantGradient. I want the htmlProps *only* contains props from HTMLAttributes.

Answer (score 0):

@spender already gave you the answer. Typescript only exists at compile time and what you are really doing is telling the compiler that props is now of type `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>`, but you are still responsible on how the `props` are composed. In sum typescript does not alter how your javascript code works, it only helps you find mistakes at compile time.

One solution for your use case is to have `htmlProps` as a property of `props` and then spread these to `Tag`.

```js
export interface Props
    extends
        VariantTheme,
        VariantSize,
        VariantGradient
{
    tag?     : keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements
    classes? : string[],
    htmlProps: React.DOMAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement>, // dom attributes is now a property in props
}
export default function Element(props: Props) {
    const elmStyles     = styles.useStyles();

    // themes:
    const variTheme     = useVariantTheme(props);
    const variSize      = useVariantSize(props);
    const variGradient  = useVariantGradient(props);



    const Tag       = (props.tag ?? 'div');
    return (
        <Tag {...props.htmlProps} // you can now pass the desired props to tag
            className={[
                elmStyles.main,
                
                // themes:
                variTheme.class,
                variSize.class,
                variGradient.class,

                ...(props.classes ?? []),
            ].filter((c) => !!c).join(' ')}
        >
            {(props as React.PropsWithChildren<Props>)?.children}
        </Tag>
    );
};
```

But @spender's suggestion is a better approach.

Don’t forget to update your hooks to accommodate this change.